# Disk utility misreporting free partition space

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I recently tried to install boot camp and I got back errors about being unable to partition the drive. I looked around and learned that I have to remove free space partitions for it to succeed. I have a 1 TB Fusion Drive, however when I checked it in disk utility, it reports an additional 1 TB of free space. [image: Disk utility misreporting free space on drive]

When I attempt to delete it, I get back the error:

```
Running operation 1 of 1: Remove “Free space” ((null)) and grow container disk2 “MacOS” (disk1s2)…
    
The target disk is too small for this operation, possibly due to partition map limits. : (-69519)
```

Running `diskutil list` outputs:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         1000.0 GB  disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *28.0 GB    disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         27.7 GB    disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk1s2, disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOS - Data            209.3 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 285.2 MB   disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                622.8 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume MacOS                   22.1 GB    disk2s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 22.1 GB    disk2s5s1
```

Running `diskutil cs list` says there are no CoreStorage logical volumes found and running `diskutil apfs list` outputs:

```
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk2 A848FFA5-8C84-4F88-B481-8C80825F8EFF
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk2 (Fusion)
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      1027680514048 B (1.0 TB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   237916794880 B (237.9 GB) (23.2% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       789763719168 B (789.8 GB) (76.8% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk1s2 A66A373E-FDD6-433F-A6FF-42C780725D32
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk1s2 (Main, "Faster" Disk Use)
    |   Size:                       27685384192 B (27.7 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 1D7BF2B5-3151-4C0F-A35B-1CA5B58142FB
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2 (Secondary, Designated Aux Use)
    |   Size:                       999995129856 B (1000.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s1 5515BBA0-41F6-4A97-9DC1-06A8CF03EB79
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s1 (Data)
    |   Name:                      MacOS - Data (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Data
    |   Capacity Consumed:         209176072192 B (209.2 GB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s2 2046C84C-B110-483C-8E8A-779BEB96139B
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Preboot
    |   Capacity Consumed:         285155328 B (285.2 MB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s3 E0E9FE63-3FA8-42DC-A177-79BAE0CFDE07
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         622776320 B (622.8 MB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s4 8700921E-3734-4141-86CB-9DBF21CFCC0F
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s4 (VM)
    |   Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/VM
    |   Capacity Consumed:         1075253248 B (1.1 GB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s5 40E5AE88-D006-4C5A-BF9F-A8544DC0B48F
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s5 (System)
        Name:                      MacOS (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Update/mnt1
        Capacity Consumed:         22125801472 B (22.1 GB)
        Sealed:                    Broken
        FileVault:                 No
        |
        Snapshot:                  3892F228-556D-45B5-BE9A-93C9B2A9E6C2
        Snapshot Disk:             disk2s5s1
        Snapshot Mount Point:      /
        Snapshot Sealed:           Yes
```

I tried running a verification of the disk in disk utility to no success. I also tried running `diskutil verifyDisk disk0`, seeminly fixing nothing and outputting:

```
Started partition map verification on disk0
Checking prerequisites
Checking the partition list
Checking the partition map size
Checking for an EFI system partition
Checking the EFI system partition's size
Checking the EFI system partition's file system
Checking the EFI system partition's folder content
Checking all HFS data partition loader spaces
Checking booter partitions
Checking Core Storage Physical Volume partitions
The partition map appears to be OK
Finished partition map verification on disk0
```

This is all on a 21.5-inch 2017 iMac running macOS Big Sur 11.6 (20G165). I am trying to install windows 21H2.

Comment: Edit your question and add the following. The output from the command `diskutil list`. The model/year of your Mac. The version of macOS (OS X) you are using. The version of Windows you are trying to install.

Comment: Your partition map may be corrupt. Try `diskutil verifyDisk disk0`

Comment: In addition to `diskutil list`, also add output of `diskutil cs list` and `diskutil apfs list`.